# Shortcut for saving file in current directory with correct name?

Tags: matlab

Is there any shortcut for saving an open file into the current directory with the current name? If I download multiple files with the same name they go into my Downloads folder and they end up with names like `function (1).m` instead of `function.m`.

At this point it's easy to open the file and see the contents by opening the file from my web browser- MATLAB sees the file extension and opens it. However, if it's a function, I have to Save As and move/rename the file before I'm able to use the code.

Edit: <strike>Since MATLAB insists that the file name be the same as the function name I'm hoping that there's a shortcut that saves an open file directly to the current MATLAB path and names it appropriately.</strike>

Since MATLAB convention is that the file name is the same as the function name I'm hoping that there's a shortcut that saves an open file directly to the current MATLAB path and names it according to the function name specified in the file.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't actually require that the function name match the filename. The issue is that the parenthesis make it an invalid function name

Comment: @Suever Ah, didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: And this is an issue with your web browser not matlab

Comment: @Suever Solving this outside of MATLAB was a good suggestion and took me just a couple of minutes. I'd still be interested if there's a shortcut of the kind described, to be used for example when writing a new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a directory which is always on the Matlab path. This can be achieved by [adding one in the `startup.m` script](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-folders-to-matlab-search-path-at-startup.html).

Then you should save the below function `savefunc.m` to that directory, so you can always call it.

```
function savefunc(FuncName, Directory)
    % Set directory if not given, default is working directory
    if nargin < 2; Directory = pwd; end
    % Get active document
    ActiveDoc = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
    % Set FuncName if not given, or if FuncName was empty string
    if nargin < 1 || strcmp(FuncName, '');
        % Get function name
        FuncName = ActiveDoc.Text;          % Entire text of document
        % Could use indexing to only take first n characters, 
        %   and not load entire string of long function into variable. 
        %   FuncName = ActiveDoc.Text(1:min(numel(ActiveDoc.Text), n));  
        FuncName = strsplit(FuncName, '('); % Split on parenthesis
        FuncName = FuncName{1};             % First item is "function [a,b,c] = myFunc"
        FuncName = strsplit(FuncName, ' '); % Split on space (functions don't always have equals)
        FuncName = strtrim(FuncName{end});  % Last item (without whitespace) is "myFunc"
    end
    % Save the file
    saveAs(ActiveDoc, fullfile(Directory, [FuncName, '.m']));    
end
```

Now, say you have just created the following `Untitled.m`:

```
function [a,b,c] = mytest()
    a = 1; b = 1; c = 1;
end
```

**The shortcut**: just have `Untitled.m` open, and type into the Command Window

```
savefunc()
```

`Untitled.m` will be saved as `mytest.m` in the current working directory. Notice you can also pass a different function name and save-as directory if you wish, making this useful for other occasions.

You can pass an empty string as the `FuncName` if you want to specify the directory but use the auto-naming.

---

You could extend this using `matlab.desktop.editor.getAll` to get all open documents, then loop through them for saving.

For more info, type `help matlab.desktop.editor` in the Command Window, online documentation seems lacking.

> matlab.desktop.editor: Programmatically access the MATLAB Editor to open, change, save, or close
>     documents.

---

Finally, note there is no need for a "Save successful" type message, since you will see the file name change, and also receive an error if it fails (from the `saveAs` docs):

> If any error occurs during the `saveAs` operation, MATLAB throws a `MATLAB:Editor:Document:SaveAsFailed` exception. If the operation returns without an exception being thrown, assume that the operation succeeded.